# Select Folder option in Dreamweaver is missing

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, dreamweaver

I have a question about *Adobe Dreamweaver*:
I have two code editors, Sublime and Dreamweaver(CS6 and CC2019 ).
Sublime has the option `select folder` to include a project at a side panel. But in Dreamweaver I'm unable to find that option. I love to code with Dreamweaver, but this option is missing.

Does Dreamweaver has the same or a similar option?